# Why must I run `git init` after `git clone`?

Tags: github

We have a GitHub repository. After I clone that repository I have to do a `git init` from command line before any Git commands will work. `git pull`, `git checkout`, etc. don't work.

As far as I know, `git init` initializes a new repository. Is it like after cloning I am creating a new repository again?

Here are the commands I'm trying to run:

```
git clone <url>
git checkout master
```

Comment: If you `git clone`, you don't need to do `git init` in that repository

Comment: Yup. But in my case I've to. Otherwise, I am unable to do push, pull, checkout etc... Basically it doesn't identify it as a git repository if I do git checkout (or any other command) after git clone. Just wondering what could go wrong?

Comment: @PuneetJain, that doesn't make any sense. Can you show the exact commands you're running? Maybe you're forgetting to change into the repository directory?

Comment: Also, what does "Someone initially uploaded the entire eclipse project as it is on github, so I doubt if its really a git repo" mean? GitHub hosts Git repositories.

Comment: Okay. Following is what I did:

1.) Clone the repository: git clone <REPO_URL>
2.) Ran git checkout. got error "not a git repository". 

Here is the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/kb3ca4

Comment: Uploaded the entire eclipse project - I mean I can see .project and .classpath related files in the repository.

Comment: @PuneetJain, the presence of `.project` and `.classpath` has nothing to do with whether something is a Git repository or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *don't* have to do `git init` in this situation¹. As pointed out in the comments, `git clone` will give you a local repository that you can start using right away.

The problem is that you're not *in* your repository when you try to run Git commands. By default, `git clone` puts the repository in a subdirectory with the same name as the repository that was cloned. You must change into that directory to use it:

```
git clone git@github.com/foo/bar.git
cd bar
```

Now that you're in `bar/` you can interact with your repository.

---

¹If you do run `git init` in the parent directory you're in for a confusing time. You'll end up with a repository in the wrong place and an inner repository containing your code. Git's behaviour with nested repositories often doesn't match users' expectations.

Answer (score 1):

After the clone, get into the projects root directory by  `cd your-project" then run git commands

In your case what happened was, you cloned the remote repository then didn't change your present working directory to the cloned project, you were in the parent of the cloned repo, since parent repo itself is not a git repository, git complained, you can't run any git commands